# ordering search results from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-like

I have a table which contains items, 2 attributes in my table are `name`(name of the item) and `keywords`(words to do with that item). When im searching for an item in the database i use the the following code. 
I have the search entry `q=""` stored in a variable `$query`.
My mysql search is the following..

```
    $q = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%$query%' OR keywords LIKE '%$query%' AND status = '1'  LIMIT $start, $per_page";
```

This code gets all my items where the name of the item is like the query or it contains a keyword which is like the query.. 
How can i order the results so that the items where the name is like the query appears before the items which contain a keyword which is like the query? 
just now it just orders the items in first added to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it this way

```lang-sql
SELECT * 
  FROM items 
 WHERE (name LIKE '%$query%' 
    OR keywords LIKE '%$query%') 
   AND status = '1' 
 ORDER BY (name LIKE '%$query%') DESC, name, keywords
 LIMIT $start, $per_page
```

**On a side note:** consider to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of interpolating query strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE statement to assign a value to `OrderValue` and then order by `OrderValue`:

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE WHEN name LIKE '%$query%' 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 2 END AS OrderValue 
FROM items 
WHERE name LIKE '%$query%' 
  OR keywords LIKE '%$query%' 
  AND status = '1' 
ORDER BY OrderValue 
LIMIT $start, $per_page
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$q = 
"SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%$query%' AND status = '1'
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM items WHERE keywords LIKE '%$query%' AND status = '1'  
 LIMIT $start, $per_page"
```